# Lookup closest value in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lookup

I have a DataFrame that contains the data shown below:

```
   soc [%]  r0 [ohm]     tau1 [s]   tau2 [s]  r1 [ohm]  r2 [ohm]     c1 [farad]    c2 [farad]
0       90  0.001539  1725.035378  54.339882  0.001726  0.001614  999309.883552  33667.261120
1       80  0.001385   389.753276  69.807148  0.001314  0.001656  296728.345634  42164.808208
2       70  0.001539   492.320311  53.697439  0.001139  0.001347  432184.454388  39865.959637
3       60  0.001539   656.942558  63.233445  0.000990  0.001515  663400.436465  41727.472274
4       50  0.001539   296.080424  53.948112  0.000918  0.001535  322490.860387  35139.878909
5       40  0.001539   501.978979  72.015509  0.001361  0.001890  368919.408585  38100.665763
6       30  0.001539   585.297624  76.972464  0.001080  0.001872  542060.285388  41114.220492
7       20  0.001385  1308.176576  60.541172  0.001426  0.001799  917348.863136  33659.124096
8       10  0.001539  1194.993755  57.078336  0.002747  0.001851  435028.073957  30839.130201
```

Given a value `z`, I want to select a row in the data frame where `soc [%]` is closest to `z`. The code below demonstrates my current approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import time


def rc_params(df, z):

    if z > 90:
        params = df.loc[0]
    elif 80 < z <= 90:
        params = df.loc[0]
    elif 70 < z <= 80:
        params = df.loc[1]
    elif 60 < z <= 70:
        params = df.loc[2]
    elif 50 < z <= 60:
        params = df.loc[3]
    elif 40 < z <= 50:
        params = df.loc[4]
    elif 30 < z <= 40:
        params = df.loc[5]
    elif 20 < z <= 30:
        params = df.loc[6]
    elif 10 < z <= 20:
        params = df.loc[7]
    else:
        params = df.loc[8]

    r0 = params['r0 [ohm]']
    tau1 = params['tau1 [s]']
    tau2 = params['tau2 [s]']
    r1 = params['r1 [ohm]']
    r2 = params['r2 [ohm]']

    return r0, tau1, tau2, r1, r2


start = time.time()

z = 20

df = pd.read_csv('results/soc_rc.csv')

r0, tau1, tau2, r1, r2 = rc_params(df, z)

end = time.time()

print(f"""
z = {z}
r0 = {r0:.4f}
tau1 = {tau1:.4f}
tau2 = {tau2:.4f}
r1 = {r1:.4f}
r2 = {r2:.4f}
run time = {end - start:.4g} s
""")
```

Results from the above code give:

```
z = 20
r0 = 0.0014
tau1 = 1308.1766
tau2 = 60.5412
r1 = 0.0014
r2 = 0.0018
run time = 0.002264 s
```

My approach works fine but is there a better (faster) way to lookup the values in the data frame? There is a [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html?highlight=lookup#pandas.DataFrame.lookup) function in Pandas but it finds exact values, so if a value doesn't exist then nothing is returned.

Comment: `min(max(9 - round(z / 10), 0), 8)`

Comment: @GarethRees I implemented `params = df.iloc[min(max(9 - round(z / 10), 0), 8)]` in the function. This gets rid of the `if` statements but execution time is the same as my original example. My goal is to find a faster way to lookup the values form the data frame compared to my original example.

Comment: @GarethRees Would working with the data in a NumPy array (instead of a DataFrame) allow me to get faster lookup times?

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this will help, but I'm using this to find nearest in a sorted column: (time series stuff)

```
result_index = df['col_to_search'].sub(search_value).abs().idxmin()
```

`.sub(search_value)` subtracts `search_value` from the `df[col_to_search]` to make the nearest value almost-zero,
`.abs()` makes the almost-zero the minimum of the column,
`.idxmin()` yields the `df.index` of the minimum value, or the closest match to search_value.

I got this approach from a similar search, but didn't note the original author or the site I found it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Do you know if this approach is faster, or is it simpler because it requires fewer lines?

Answer (score 4):

Adapting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112103/7486879) would be a cleaner way to do what you want.

```
params = df.iloc[(df['soc [%]']-z).abs().argsort()[:1]]
```

There might be faster ways if your `soc [%]` column is fixed with those values.

Also, you should consider not measuring the time for `pd.read_csv` as that isn't what you are wanting to know the execution for.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about measuring the execution time. I have updated my question with the new timing result. I also tried your suggestion using `argsort()` which gets rid of the `if` statements but unfortunately this is about 3 times slower than my original example.

Comment: Wouldn't `idxmax()` be better than `argsort()[:1]`?

Comment: @GarethRees Using `idxmax()` does not give the correct results; however, `idxmin()` gives the right results but it is still about 3 times slower than my original example.

Comment: @wigging, you are essentially hardcoding a lookup table with your elifs. Its going to be hard to speed that part up dramatically. 

In the speedup context, there are a couple options:

1. Speed up the elifs ( you could do this with a binary tree)

2. Speed up the lookups ( you could do this with 1 lookup)

    `r0, tau1, tau2, r1, r2   = params[['r0 [ohm]', 'tau1 [s]', 'tau2 [s]', 'r1 [ohm]', 'r2 [ohm]']]`